# drupal 7 site migration to root from beta (sub folder)

Tags: drupal, migration, drupal-7, beta

I have following site in drupal 7
[Test Site](http://zhncontracting.com/beta/) and now I want to move the site to root folder. I mean from beta to public html folder. Please guide!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should just be able to move the files out of `beta` into the root to be honest, pretty much all paths in Drupal are dynamic. The only couple of caveats are:

1. If you've set the site up with a `$base_url` pointing to the beta subfolder you'll need to edit `sites/default/files/settings.php` and comment that change out (have a look at the file and you'll know if/why you need to do this).
2. If you have images/files embedded in content that have static links to '/beta/some-file' those will need to be changed manually.

Answer (score 0):

Go to **Configuration > Site information**, (**admin/config/system/site-information**) and then change **default front page**: to *beta*.